# JQuery Mobile - always show back button, regardless of entry point

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm making a mobile site with JQuery Mobile and need to allow entry to any section and still allow the user to navigate backwards.

Example to show what I mean. The JQuery Mobile demo site starts at:

```
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/
```

If I click on "Toolbars" I reach:

```
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/toolbars/index.html
```

There is a back-button which leads to the previous site. But if I manually enter the above toolbar URL into my browser the page will not have a back button.

How can I accomplish to always have a back button, while still keeping the nice AJAX backed page loads? The server back-end will generate all html-pages so it's fine to "hard code" what the previous section is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's fine to hardcode, then just add

```
<a href="hardcodedprevious" data-icon="back" />
```

to the header